# How to enable OpenVPN access to ONLY the internal LAN

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup an OpenVPN connection to a company server so that anyone working from home or is out of the office can access our internal resources.

I have the VPN setup correctly, using a guide on Digital Ocean's blog (written for 16.04).

I can connect from an outside line, ping the internal servers and devices and access their resources. This works great.

However, we want to limit the connection to only internal resources. We don't want to pass through an internet connection via the OpenVPN, which isn't the typical use for a VPN (masking connection, by-passing Geoblocking or just encrypting your connection).

Is this possible? I know obviously the VPN connection needs to be able to talk to the client, but outside this I want to block all connections to the web otherwise.

The server in question is also a VM running on another machine.

Comment: Once you connect to the target machine, you have all its capabilities. You'd have to keep it from accessing the internet.

Comment: But then how do I do that without blocking OpenVPN from polling on port 1194 for a connection which comes via the internet?

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Comment: So basically it's not possible to have a VPN that is accessible remotely, but cannot connect to the internet itself?

Comment: I am no expert, but if you use a VPN to connect to a machine that can access the internet, you can access the internet.

Comment: I use VPNs daily to access private networks... When the VPN is created you get a new interface (vpnX). Connection to the VPN also changes the routing tables so that addresses corresponding to systems in the network connected to by VPN  are routed through that interface. The rest is routed normally, so the VPN client machine can access both the Internet and the private network. But the VPN setup can define a more global routing so that all traffic is routed to the VPN, thus preventing the use of Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to just access the internal resources without internet connection, i think this is actually the usual scenario for using OpenVPN. 
So if you followed some guide to setup OpenVPN server, there were also some steps that allowed forwarding clients traffic to the internet, you'll need to undo those steps.
I think you should start with commenting this line in *server.conf*

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Then pushing a DNS server for clients should be disabled by commenting out lines that look like

```
    push "dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Ofcourse you'll need to reload OpenVpn conf after making the changes.

```
    sudo service openvpn reload
```

And then disabling packet forwarding out to the internet

```
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

And to make disabling forwarding permanent you'll also have to edit

```
    /etc/sysctl.conf
```

commenting line

```
    net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

By now i think clients shouldn't anymore be able to access the internet through VPN.

Comment: I also needed to remove the line `push "block-outside-dns"`

Comment: work great for me, Windows 10 (client), Ubuntun VM (server)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it different way on client side

Windows:
You have to open VPN connection settings
Then Networking > TCP/IPv4 > Properties > Advanced - Disable "Use default gateway for remote networks" option

Comment: I actually used this solution on a totally different scenario as well, though prior to reading this!

Comment: I will leave the other answer as accepted because it's quite in depth but this is valid as well.