# ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.200 port 22: No route to host

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, docker

The context is the following:

I have installed Ubuntu server in a device at my home and set up a ssh server in this device. I can connect to this Ubuntu server through ssh without problems if the client device (Laptop in my case) is in the same local network.
As I would like to access the server remotely, I installed openvpn3, this connection works fine too.
But when I try to ssh (connected to another network, let's call "network B", than the server is, but with VPN connection active), I get the message:

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.200 port 22: No route to host`

I guess the reason is that network B's gateway tries to route to the devices inside network B's LAN instead of the server LAN.
But I need to access the server's LAN in order to connect through ssh to my server with the private static IP address I set up to it.

Server's public IP:

```bsh
$ curl ifconfig.me
181.31.117.40
```

Answering to @cocomac

> Just to check the obvious... is it 192.168.0. 200 or 192.168.1.200? Typically 192.168.1.XYZ is the default –

Proof that `192.168.0.200` is the server's IP:

```bsh
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp37s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:f0:5d:78:39:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.200/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp37s0
       valid_lft 2528sec preferred_lft 2528sec
    inet6 fe80::2ef0:5dff:fe78:39a8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

SSH when my laptop is in the same LAN:

```bsh
sebastian@sebastian-Vostro-3405:~$ ssh sebademasi10@192.168.0.200 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-100-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon 28 Feb 2022 12:54:15 AM UTC

  System load:                      0.09
  Usage of /:                       13.5% of 97.93GB
  Memory usage:                     45%
  Swap usage:                       0%
  Processes:                        311
  Users logged in:                  0
  IPv4 address for br-5c5a41a7cc73: 172.19.0.1
  IPv4 address for br-974f16cf42ed: 172.18.0.1
  IPv4 address for docker0:         172.17.0.1
  IPv4 address for enp37s0:         192.168.0.200

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

0 updates can be applied immediately.


Last login: Mon Feb 28 00:48:56 2022 from 192.168.0.110
sebademasi10@home:~$
```

Now, changing to my **neighbor's network**, I connect thought VPN:

```bsh
~$ openvpn3 session-start -c home 
Using pre-loaded configuration profile 'home'
Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/ca62d16csfcfcs43f1sa320s14f8bd92193e
Connected
```

Check Public IP:

```bsh
sebastian@sebastian-Vostro-3405:~$ curl ifconfig.me
181.31.117.40
```

`ip route`:

```bsh
$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-aa3d18e9a788 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-7c64d12635b8 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-118925d85563 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
181.31.117.40 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.110 metric 600 
192.168.255.1 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
192.168.255.4/30 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.255.6
```

**NOTE:**

- Ther VPN server runs inside a Docker container

I hope this is easy to understand, please feel free to ask for any other details you consider needed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to check the obvious... is it 192.168.0. 200 or 192.168.1.200? Typically 192.168.1.XYZ is the default

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show us `ip route`. Don't reply via "Add Comment".

Comment: Done @user68186

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. If you connect your laptop to the **neighbor's network** and not connect to the VPN, can you `ssh` into your home Ubuntu server using the external IP address of your home network? Once you connect to the "home" VPN, can you ping `192.168.0.200`? What is the purpose of the "home" VPN: (a) access the internet using your "home" ISP as the gateway, or (b) access the computers in your "home" network from outside, or both (a) and (b)?

Comment: @user68186 I have enabled ssh to access server within the home LAN, so if I do `ssh sebademasi10@192.168.0.200` it works if the client is connected to same LAN than server. Your (b) describes better my purpose. At my work I can use the private IP address to connect throught ssh i.e `ssh 10.250.28.28` to devices within of the same LAN in which VPN server runs. I think I need a way to tell that 192.168.0.200 is outside the neighbor's LAN and it belongs to 185.x.x.x (public IP of home network)

Comment: Please read [the **first part** of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267872/remote-desktop-access-between-2-ubuntu-20-04-devices-over-the-internet/1267978#1267978) and verify that you have setup your openvpn profile to do (b) and not (a). Some routers have built-in VPN server that allows (b) kind of access to your home network.

Comment: Putting the VPN server inside a docker container adds another layer of complexity. Also see [How to enable OpenVPN access to ONLY the internal LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776324/how-to-enable-openvpn-access-to-only-the-internal-lan)

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to check whether the profile of VPN I set up is able to do your (b) option. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by manually adding (after connect to VPN) the route as follows:

`ip route add 192.168.0.200 via 192.168.255.5`

Where:

- 192.168.0.200 is the server's private IP
- 192.168.255.5 is the IP of the gateway in the server network

I realized this by checking `ip route`:

```
$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-aa3d18e9a788 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-7c64d12635b8 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-118925d85563 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
181.31.117.40 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.110 metric 600 
192.168.0.200 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
192.168.255.1 via 192.168.255.5 dev tun0 
192.168.255.4/30 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.255.6
```